Mode Switching Challenges in MPPT and CC-CV Converters for Battery-to-Battery Charging
This project involves the design of a system that enables energy storage and transfer between two 12V, 12Ah batteries using a solar panel as the energy source. The system utilizes a 12V, 60W solar panel, and the energy from the panel is regulated to a stable 13.6V using a Buck-Boost converter, ensuring safe and efficient charging of the batteries.
The energy management within the system is performed automatically based on the voltage levels of the batteries. For this purpose, an Arduino microcontroller is employed. The Arduino continuously measures the voltage levels of the batteries and controls the relays accordingly. Initially, the energy from the solar panel is directed to charge battery B2. Once B2 is fully charged, the Arduino switches the relay positions to start charging battery B1. Similarly, when B1 is full, the system redirects energy from B1 to charge B2, managing this process automatically.
The relays are triggered by the Arduino based on the state of charge of the batteries, enabling seamless circuit transitions. This eliminates the need for manual intervention and optimizes the energy flow. The automation based on Arduino's voltage measurements makes the system flexible and efficient.
This design provides a cost-effective energy management solution using a single Buck-Boost converter to charge multiple batteries and transfer energy between them effectively. Aiming to maximize the utilization of solar energy, this project offers a modern and automated solution for sustainable energy management.
If we use the converter provided in the link, which supports both MPPT and CC-CV modes, would switching to MPPT mode during battery-to-battery charging cause any issues? Specifically, can the converter automatically detect the appropriate mode based on the source and load, or would manual intervention be required to prevent problems during battery-to-battery charging?
https://tr.aliexpress.com/item/32971948927.html?src=google

How will it know the chemistry and SoC and if the charge current includes any load current?

When the battery voltage drops below a certain threshold, it can be considered "empty," and the charging process will be initiated. Similarly, when the voltage exceeds a certain upper limit, it will be considered "fully charged," and the charging process will stop.

that converter doesn't appear to have MPPT implemented. You would be much better off with a linear regular or Arduino-based PWM to handle power from the PV than you would using a B+B DC-DC, which inevitably attempt to pull too much current from the PV, overshooting the MPP.

I suspect the power supply DOESN'T have MPPT mode. I think the text means that it has CCCV mode BUT if you want to use it for solar use that a MPPT capable device would be better. || The modue IS capable of MPPT action IF you control it extermally - in this case by your Arduino. MPPT may be useful for solar charging. You need to provide more informatio about your PV panel specs. A 12V nominal panel is often 18V Vmp. This means that a 60W panel is rated at I = P/V  = 60W/18V = 3.33 A at maximum power point in full sun. || For solar charging the converter can give maybe != 30% more current.

For battery to battery use you can set the converter to deliver the desired maximum charge current. I can orovide a fuller answer if nobody else does.

@RussellMcMahon I was trying to use MPPT in the converter, I don’t how it works. I know the algorithm tracks the maximum input power, but I’m unsure how it does so. If I gather feedback from both the input and output voltage and current to track the maximum power and then adjust the duty cycle accordingly, how does the output voltage remain constant? Since I always need a fixed output voltage of 14V for battery charging, which is the converter’s output voltage, I don’t understand how the adjustments to track the maximum power at the input don’t affect the output voltage.

The 14V (or whatever you choose) is the final floar voltage. The battery voltage will be lower during charging. You want tomaximise charging current for a given insolation (sunshine level). This is achieved by holding the panel at it's maximum power voltage = Vmp. You can optimise power (true MPPT) or match a preset curve OR can get a good approxiomatiion by holding panel at ABOUT 80 - 85% of its Vmp = max rated voltage. You can experiment to see which voltage is best. You then adjust the converter to give max current into battery at this Vin. ...

This can probably be approximated by setting a Vout target voltage  slightly above Vbattery_current.
